# Assigning an Object a modified version of itself using methods - Bad practice?

Tags: java, performance, class, structure

I'll make it short:

```
public aClass[] changeClassSlightly(aClass[] ac) {
    // changing various things in the class
    // changes done
    return ac;
}
```

meanwhile, in the main:

```
aClass test = new aClass();
test = changeClassSlightly(test);
```

So,
is this an inefficient / looked-down-uppon or unstandard way of doing things, when wanting to implement a functionality regarding a certain class into a different class?

In my case, the here called "aClass" is a fairly simple one, but when these things get bigger and bigger, taking the whole object and spitting it out slightly changed may be considered bad programming.

Is it, though? Is it the sighn of bad data structure or common practise in Java development?

Thanks a lot in advance and thanks for bearing with me :)

Comment: Your types are confusing me a bit. The method has return type `aClass[]`, but you're treating it as though it returned `aClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two different questions here. Inside of `changeClassSlightly(...)`, it looks like you're talking about mutating the `ac` argument. The code in your question also seems to be asking about local variable reuse, since `test` is both the argument and the variable containing the value returned by `changeClassSlightly(...)`.

In general, I personally prefer using immutable objects and data structures. I also try to avoid mutating arguments. See *Effective Java,* Item 15: Minimize Mutability.

If a function is pure it's generally easier to reason about.

But this is very much a matter of opinion.

As for reusing the local variable: I try to avoid doing that, too, but it's really not a big deal either way.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective your code is not ideal. If you can set values in the constructor you can use final fields (immutable, so always thread-safe and easy for the JVM to optimize). Furthermore the values set in the constructor can be safely read without synchronization. If you use a setter later on you need to synchronize or risk not getting the new value in other threads. Synchronization is not as expensive as it once was, but it should be avoided where possible.

I would recommend the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) instead.